# Bullet not getting Instantiated when destroyed - Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to using unity and I am still learning C#. So pls bear with me if the problem mentioned below may seem a little odd or easy to fix.

I am creating a project in order to try to shoot a bullet from a turret, and I have included a function in my bullet script that will destroy the bullet after it has crossed certain boundaries and a function in my bulletSpawner script to Instantiate the bullet if it is destroyed. For some reason whenever I play and shoot the bullet and it crosses the boundary, it doesn't get cloned

Here is the Bullet script;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float Power = 50f;

    private Rigidbody2D myBody;

    private SpriteRenderer sr;

    private float posX;

    private float posY;

    private void Awake()
    {
        myBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Shoot();
        destroyBullet();
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
           myBody.AddForce(new Vector2(Power, Power - myBody.gravityScale), 
           ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }

    void destroyBullet()
    {
        posX = transform.position.x;
        posY = transform.position.y;
        if (posX > 100 || posX < -100 || posY > 100 || posY < -100)
            Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}//class
```

Here is the BulletSpawner script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform bullet; 

    void Update()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnBullet());
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnBullet()
    {
        while (!GameObject.FindWithTag("Bullet"))
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

            Instantiate(bullet);

        }//while
    }//Ienum        
}//class
```

Note: I have attached my Bullet Prefab to bullet in the inspector panel

Whenever the bullet is out of bounds, or gets destroyed, I get this error:

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Transform' has been destroyed but you are still
> trying to access it.

I know it has been destroyed but I want to find a way to access it so that it can clone the bullet(which can be fired again, destroyed and so on...)

Please advise on what I can do to fix this code, or any alternatives in order to prevent such errors from happening in the future. Any feedback would be appreciated :) ...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where exactly is your exception thrown from? Could you include the stacktrace? Also **!attention!** you do **not** want to start a new Coroutine **every frame** in `Update`!

Comment: And another question: why is the `Shoot` method on the bullet itself? Shouldn't it rather be on the spawner and you shoot/instantiate a bullet when pressing space?

Comment: And it sounds like as the prefab to be instantiated you used the original `bullet` instance from the scene -> don't! You rather want to use an actual prefab asset .. otherwise you can't instantiate something that has been destroyed ;)

Comment: I tried Adding the shoot method on the spawner, but for some reason, it wasnt moving, when I attached it to the bullet, it worked fine

Comment: Then can you pls suggest any alternative  \so that the prefab can be accessed.
Btw what is a stacktrace??

Comment: `it wasnt moving` well you would need to apply the force to the bullet, not the spawner. And in general make a prefab from the bullet and use this as prefab instead.

Comment: I guess you are talking about this: 

MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Transform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate[T] (T original) (at <d3b66f0ad4e34a55b6ef91ab84878193>:0)
BulletSpawner+<SpawnBullet>d__2.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/BulletSpawner.cs:20)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at <d3b66f0ad4e34a55b6ef91ab84878193>:0)

Comment: Consider _recycling_ your rapidly recreated objects rather than re-spawning them.  It's nicer to the memory heap and will prove more efficient when the player gets that _gattling cannon upgrade_.   Simply _move_ that bullet that went out of frame

Comment: Yes because now we know for sure that the error is that `bullet` is destroyed and you try to use it as parameter for `Instantiate` .. which means as said you are using an actual scene object as original but you rather want to create a prefab from it and use that one instead

Comment: Ok @derHugo I have done what you said with regards to the prefab, now when it gets destroyed, many bullets get spawned at once, so should I include the coroutine in the start function instead?

Comment: Can you pls tell how to recycle the bullets @MickyD

Comment: `so should I include the coroutine in the start function instead` for example and wrap it into one more infinite while loop or actually like e.g. `IEnumerator Start() { while(true){ yield return new WaitUntil(() => !GameObject.FindWithTag("Bullet")); yield return new WaitForSeconds (3); Instantiate (bullet); }`

Comment: @ANM _"Can you pls tell how to recycle the bullets"_ - as mentioned above, no need to destroy it, simply _move_ the bullet back to the start position on the turret.  You'll need to update the initial velocity/direction of course

Comment: Thanks derHugo and MickyD , I tried both methods and they both worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as already mentioned the main issue was you used the original scene instance as original `bullet` for the `Instantiate` but then destroyed that original.

**If** you are going to use destroy and instantiate you rather want a **prefab asset** as `bullet` original.

However, after also what MickyD mentioned: You will always have one single bullet at a time anyway so you probably don't have to destroy it at all. Simply reuse the very same bullet instance.

And then regarding the Shoot and your Coroutine in `Update` this is how I would rather do it

The bullet itself doesn't do anything at all and is rather only passive.

And then do

```
public class BulletSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Now again the one from the Scene!
    public Rigidbody2D bullet; 

    // Yes if Start is IEnumerator it is automatically run as Coroutine by Unity
    IEnumerator Start ()
    {
        // Disable the Rigidbody of the bullet so it doesn't fall down
        bullet.isKinematic = true;

        // Huh?! This is okey in an IEnumerator as long as you yield inside
        while(true)
        {
            // wait until Space is pressed
            yield return new WaitUntil (() => Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space));

            // enable the Rigidbody
            bullet.isKinematic = false;
            // shoot the bullet
            bullet.AddForce(new Vector2(Power, Power - bullet.gravityScale), ForceMode2D.Impulse);

            // Now wait until it is out of bounds
            //TODO: .. or it hits something ;)
            yield return new WaitUntil (() => bullet.position.magnitude > 100f /*TODO || hasHitSomething */);

            // Then reset it's movement
            bullet.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            bullet.angularVelocity = 0;
            // Reset position
            bullet.position = Vector2.zero;
            bullet.rotation = 0;
            bullet.transform.position = Vector2.zero;
            bullet.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
            // disable the Rigidbody for the next iteration
            bullet.isKinematic = true;

            // Disable the entire object
            bullet.gameObject.SetActive(false);

            // Wait for the cooldown
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (3);

            // enable the object (but not yet the Rigidbody)
            bullet.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

---

for checking the `hasHitSomething` I would put a dedicated component on the bullet like e.g.

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool hasCollided;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        hasCollided = true;
    }
}
```

ad then

```
yield return new WaitUntil (() => bullet.position.magnitude > 100f || bullet.GetComponent<Bullet>().hasCollided);

// reset the flag
bullet.GetComponent<Bullet>().hasCollided = false;
```

you should of course in general rather store the `Bullet` reference and not use `GetComponent` repeatedly.

Comment: After implementing your code and saving, there are compilation errors stating that: 'Rigidbody2D' does not contain a definition for 'enabled' and no accessible extension method 'enabled' accepting a first argument of type 'Rigidbody2D' could be found...
This may be because rigidbody can not be enabled or disabled... 
Kindly suggest how to fix it.

Comment: Note: The checkbox near the Rigidbody2D component is also not visible.

Comment: @ANM my bad ^^ only typed this on the phone .. you can use `isKinematic` instead which also disables physics for this object and rather makes it "controlled only by code" .. but since we don't move this via code it basically will simply stay where it is ;)

Comment: Thank-you good sir.  +1 for yesterday :)

Comment: The bullet doesn't revert it's position to the origin after it goes out of bounds, this may be because  in the code, bullet is declared as the rigidbody for my Bullet object (this meant that the rigidbody will revert it's position back to the origin, not the Bullet object itelf...which doesn't make sense!) . I have added a transform component in my answer down below...

Comment: @ANM well if you reset the Rigidbody position it should reset it's position with the next physics update .. but I guess it doesn't come to that since we disable the gameObject .. you could though simply do the same also for the transform additionally

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just a slight correction to the code that derHugo has written above,

Here is the edited version, the changes are marked in ** below...

```
public class BulletSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
   
    public Rigidbody2D bullet;
    public Transform bulletPos;//change**

    [SerializeField]
    private float Power = 50f;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnBullets());
    }

    void Update() { 

    }
    
    IEnumerator SpawnBullets()
    {
        
        bullet.simulated = false;
       
        while (true)
        {
            
            yield return new WaitUntil(() => Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space));
           
            bullet.simulated = true;
            
            bullet.AddForce(new Vector2(Power, Power - bullet.gravityScale), 
            ForceMode2D.Impulse);

            
            yield return new WaitUntil(() => bullet.position.magnitude > 100f  
            || hasHitSomething */);

    
            bullet.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            bullet.angularVelocity = 0;
          
            bulletPos.position = Vector2.zero;//change**
            bullet.rotation = 0;
           
            bullet.simulated = false;

         
            bullet.gameObject.SetActive(false);

     
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

         
            bullet.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I have done the two changes because when the bullet gets fired and goes out of bounds, the bullet's position does not go back to it's original position (that is (0,0)) that may be because in the code, bullet is declared as the rigidbody for my Bullet object (this meant that the rigidbody will revert it's position back to the origin, not the Bullet object itelf...which doesn't make sense!) .So I had to declare bulletPos as the Transform component of the Bullet object and change bullet to bulletPos in

```
bullet.position = Vector2.zero;
```

This is to ensure that the Bullet object instead of the bullet rigidbody reverts it's position back to the origin.

Don't forget to attach the transform component of the bullet to the script in bulletSpawner, then it will run smoothly...

Just wanted to include this so that the same mistake is not made again.

Comment: Special thanks to derHugo and MickyD for helping me solve this issue ;)

Comment: Note: I have used .simulated instead of .isKinematic.... both work.