# Collision detected, but code which gets active when collision occurs does not work - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

Here is the code for the object which will collide...

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    //declaring some components
    private string GROUND_TAG = "Ground";
    private static bool hasCollided;
    public static bool HasCollided
    {
        get { return hasCollided; }
        set { hasCollided = value; }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        // getting the components
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag(GROUND_TAG))
        {
            //Debug.Log("Grounded");
            hasCollided = true;
            //Debug.Log(hasCollided);
        }
    }
}//class
```

After setting hasCollided public as HasCollided, I have written the script for the Turret...

```
public class Turret : MonoBehaviour
{
    //declaring some components
    bool collided = Bullet.HasCollided;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnBullets());
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnBullets()
    {
        //some code
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitUntil(() => Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space));

            //some more code
            yield return new WaitUntil(() => bullet.position.magnitude > 100f || collided);//*
            //Debug.Log(collided);
            // Resetting the movement and position for the next iteration
            bullet.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            bullet.angularVelocity = 0;
            bulletPos.position = Vector2.zero;
            bullet.rotation = 0;
            //some code
        
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
            //some other code
        }
    }
}//class
```

In the line (*), when the bullet goes out of bounds, the code below works, but if a collision occurs, as mentioned in

> || collided);//*

then the code below does not work.(And shows no compilation errors)

Pls suggest what to do to fix this issue

Comment: I thought I already had added an example of how I would check for the collision in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70830374/7111561) .. I updated it with a simplier solution btw without events ;)

Comment: Besides that I would not only check for the ground ... what if you hit something else on the way?

Comment: Good Point... BTw I had made a new post for this question so that the code whose issue was being addressed in the previous question may look a bit less tedious.... anyway after implementing your method, I am getting a  'Rigidbody2D' does not contain a definition for 'hasCollided' type error.  and when I try writing Bullet with a capital B( addressing the object) in line 'bullet.hasCollided = false;' ,  then I get this error: 'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Bullet.hasCollided' .... Sorry for the inconvenience...

Comment: If you look closely it is not `bullet.hasCollided` but `bullet.GetComponent<Bullet>().hasCollided`

Comment: Thanks a ton..... it worked now.... 